# SQL Server 2005 Express - could not open a connection

Tags: sql-server-express, sql-server-2005-express

I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express edition on my Vista Ultimate computer. However, when it opens I enter my computer name / SQLEXPRESS. When I click the Connect button, it gives me an error message.

Under the configuration tools I cannot find the SQL Server Surface Area Configuration. It only has SQL Server Error and Usage Reporting.

The error message I receive when I click the Connect button is:

> A network related or instance specific error occurred while establsihing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that the SQL server is confugured to allow remote connection (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error 40- Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server : error 67)

Comment: SQL error messages make it easy to copy them - just click the little copy icon in the lower left corner of the error message dialog.

Comment: a network related or instance specific error occurred while establsihing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that the SQL server is confugured to allow remote connection (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error 40- Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server : error 67)

Comment: please do not post long error messages etc. in comments - those are really hard to read. Instead, please update your original question by editing it and add the new information there and format it properly - much better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another thing to check for is the account that the SQL Express service is running under. I think it defaults to network service, but I typically run it under Local System (or if you're feeling ambitious, make a service account for it). This has taken care of a handful of permission issues I've had with SQL Express in the past.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, as you'd written, it appears the slash is incorrect. Try:

```
.\SQLEXPRESS
```

Also ensure that your SQL Server services are started. Run `services.msc` and find `SQL Server(SQLExpress)`.